# Cannot Write Over TCP Network Stream

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm encountering a problem when I try to write over a network stream.

When I press this button here, I can successfully write to the tcp stream and the other part of the program successfully receives the data.

```
Dim ClientSocket As TcpClient

Private Sub btnConnect_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnConnect.MouseClick

          ClientSocket = New TcpClient

          ClientSocket.Connect(frmNetworkSettings.txtServerIPAddress.Text, CInt(frmNetworkSettings.txtFileSharingPort.Text))

          Dim NetworkStream As NetworkStream = ClientSocket.GetStream()

          If NetworkStream.CanRead And NetworkStream.CanWrite Then

                 Dim SentData As Byte()

                 SentData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username & Chr(32) & "is connected." & Environment.NewLine)

                 NetworkStream.Write(SentData, 0, SentData.Length())

                 NetworkStream.Flush()

          End If

End Sub
```

But when I press this button below, after pressing the button above, I cannot write on the tcp network stream and the other program on the network receives no data.

```
Private Sub btnDisconnect_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnDisconnect.MouseClick

         Dim NetworkStream As NetworkStream = ClientSocket.GetStream()

         If NetworkStream.CanRead And NetworkStream.CanWrite Then

                Dim SentData As Byte()

                SentData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username & Chr(32) & "is disconnected." & Environment.NewLine)

                NetworkStream.Write(SentData, 0, SentData.Length())

                NetworkStream.Flush()

         End If

End Sub
```

**Additional Details:**

This is the part that receives the data on the other program.

```
Private Sub ConnectionTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ConnectionTimer.Tick

    Try

        If Listener.Pending Then

            ClientSocket = Listener.AcceptTcpClient

            Dim ByteData(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte

            Dim NetworkStream As NetworkStream = ClientSocket.GetStream

            Dim LogMessage As String = String.Empty

            NetworkStream.Read(ByteData, 0, CInt(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))

            LogMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteData)

            DisplayLogMessage(LogMessage)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get, and what is the stack trace?

Comment: There is no error. It just doesn't send the data. I checked the string on the other program if it receives data but it doesn't.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to walk through to see if you are enter the code?  Also, you are not checking the return value of Write and you should be.  And NetworkStream.Flush doesn't do anything and should be removed.

Comment: Ok, but how do I check the value of Write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Its because I'm reading the network stream only during a connection is made. I should modify my code to read the network stream after a connection is made.